# Is this a bug in 7z 9.20 for linux ($ character in password)?

Tags: linux, shell, passwords, 7zip

7-Zip 9.20 on i686-pc-linux-gnu

1. create archive

> /usr/syno/bin/7z a "/volume1/test.7z" "/volume1/file.txt"
>   -xr!thumbs.db -xr!@eaDir -xr!@tmp -xr!#recycle -xr!lost+found -xr!.DS_Store -t7z -ms=off -mhe -mmt -mx0 -v10m -p"pa$ss$12"

2. now try to extract file "file.txt" from archive "test.7z" in windows (7-Zip File Manager 16.04) with the same password
3. in my case password is always incorrect :(((

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: You're not passing the arguments you think you are. To see what arguments you're actually passing to the command, prepend `echo` to your command.

Answer (score 0):

The $ is being interpreted by the shell as a variable.  You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
/usr/syno/bin/7z a "/volume1/test.7z" "/volume1/file.txt" -xr!thumbs.db -xr!@eaDir -xr!@tmp -xr!#recycle -xr!lost+found -xr!.DS_Store -t7z -ms=off -mhe -mmt -mx0 -v10m -p'pa$ss$12'
```